# Demonstrating iPad's screen on MacBook

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, airplay, streaming

I need to use my iPad and show its screen on my MacBook. As far as I know, AirPlay allows me to use the iPad as a second screen for Mac but here I need to do it the opposite way.

I can't record my iPad's screen or use Continuity Sketch (in fact I need this mostly for drawing on my iPad only).

Can I stream or mirror  my iPad's screen on my Mac?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Connect your iPad via cable to your MacBook.
2. Launch macOS built-in QuickTime Player.app
3. Go to File menu → New Movie Recording or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
4. This would open a Quick Time window with the MacBooks camera turned on.
5. Click on the arrow besides the red circular Record button and select your iPad for Camera.

[image]

6. This would show the iPad's screen on your Mac. It won't let you interact with the iPad, simply stream the screen contents.

[image]

7. If you rotate the iPad to change to landscape mode, the display changes to follow.

[image]

8. You can click inside the Quick Time player window to make the controls and window borders disappear and you can also take the app window full screen if you want only the iPad's screen to appear on your Mac.

[image]

You do not need any 3rd party software or hardware to accomplish this and it works out of the box.

**P.S.**: If you are only interested in viewing the iPad's display on your Mac, you need not press the Record button, and no extra memory or disk space would be used. (Thanks, [@alexkent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392568/demonstrating-ipads-screen-on-macbook/392576?noredirect=1#comment539913_392576) for stating it explicitly).

Comment: Is there a way without connecting via cable? And if I start recording then I need to make sure I have enough free space, right?

Comment: And what about 3rd party software? Just it looks like there must be a better way. I'm gonna pass my exam which can last for hours (up to 6 hours on average, I'm not kidding) and recording it the whole time...

Comment: @MarkTiukov Some 3rd party apps can let you connect wirelessly (by making your Mac an AirPlay target). One such app is [Reflector 3](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector). And yes, you'd have be to mindful of storage space and memory if doing a lengthy recording.

Comment: With a cable as describe above is the most reliable. You do not need to be recording in QuickTime Player, so Mac disk space isn’t a concern. Apps like Reflector can work great but rely on good WiFi.

Comment: @alexkent Thank you for making it explicit to not press the record button. While I didn't mention anywhere to press the Record button, I think it would be a good idea to explicitly mention it.