# How do you screen mirror from an iPad to a Mac when they are not signed into the same Apple ID?

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, ipad, apple-id, airplay

I'm trying to mirror a movie using (SharePlay? AirPlay?) to my Mac from a friend's iPad; however, because we are not signed into our devices with the same Apple ID, it won't allow screen mirroring. **How can I mirror content from an iPad to my Mac without using the same Apple ID on both devices?**

Comment: You can try mirroring it using quick time player, via a USB c cable

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392568/demonstrating-ipads-screen-on-macbook/392576#392576